# How to set a git repository's remote url without updating the local repository it's cloned from?

Tags: linux, git, github

There is no remote repository for this project yet but it has a remote set in its config and someone did that for some reason so I won't change it. The original repository is in /home/me/repo1/.git and I ran `git clone /home/me/repo1/.git` while in /home/me/repo2 so now it's cloned in /repo2
When I go into the cloned repo and run `git remote set-url origin http://example.com/asdf/.git` both repositories config's get updated.

I can't fork the repo because I don't have admin access and no access to gh cli or similar tools. Is there a workaround to only update the second repository?

Comment: I've posted an answer but then noticed that you cloned, rather than copying. I've replicated the proposed scenario again and cannot reproduce the proposed issue. Cloning while in `[...]/repo2` folder, will generate a `repo1` folder inside it, so I suppose that you ran the `git remote set-url` command inside `[...]/repo2/repo1`, is that correct? When the remote was set inside it, the url was properly updated, only for the cloned one, as expected, since the configuration is independent on both of them.

Comment: I've edited it and added it back, could you please check the steps performed? It would not fit a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot simulate the issue here, and it makes sense, since the remote tracking configuration is on a per repository basis, could you please check if the performed steps resemble the steps provided below? The intent of the `pwd` commands is to demonstrate the current folder in which the subsequent commands are executed.

1. Create repo1

```
$ pwd
/home/user/
$ mkdir repo1
$ cd repo1
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/daniel/Temporary/repo1/.git/
$ git remote add origin http://url.com/repo1.git
```

2. Create repo2

```
$ pwd
/home/user/
$ mkdir repo2
$ cd repo2
$ git clone ../repo1/.git/
Cloning into 'repo1'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
```

3. Set remote url for cloned repository

```
$ pwd
/home/user/repo2/repo1
$ git remote set-url origin http://url.com/repo2.git
```

4. Retrieve the remote urls

```
$ pwd
/home/user/repo1
$ git remote -v
origin  http://url.com/repo1.git (fetch)
origin  http://url.com/repo1.git (push)

-----

$ pwd
/home/user/repo2/repo1
$ git remote -v
origin  http://url.com/repo2.git (fetch)
origin  http://url.com/repo2.git (push)
```

Comment: You are 100% right. The "issue" here is a mistake about paths and your pwd statements are what I should have been doing to ensure I was in the right directory because what was happening was the cloned repository finds itself in a folder in repo2 called repo1. So I was seeing ```user@machine repo1 % git config --get remote.origin.url``` with a response of repo2's remote and I was thinking a reference was pointing back to the actual repo1 but this was the repo1 in repo2. Silly mistake on my part, thank you so much for the clear answer!

Comment: Awesome, thank you for answering back, glad that it was helpful!

Comment: Just a follow up but I'm noticing that repo2 (the clone of repo1) has none of the tags or branches of repo1. The refs/tags folder is empty. Do you know if this is normal behavior?

Comment: Yes, this is the normal behaviour, the reflog is local to the repository and branches are independent and per repository basis. When you clone the repository, you are cloning the master/main branch.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_description) of `git clone` it states that it "[...]creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository [...]" - and since your repository is local, there are no remote branches - "[...] and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch" - which explains why there is only one branch